# A syntax error in temp folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I use XAMPP and PhpStorm and WordPress was installed in my local server. When I open WordPress URL in local suddenly this error is happening:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in C:\Users\iman\AppData\Local\Temp\theD36B.tmp on line 2
```

and in the `theD36B.tmp` I see this code:

```
<?php
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /txt.txt was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

I found that this file is created automatically and any time I refresh the page new file is created. I do not know how this problem can be solved.

Comment: You need to remove starting PHP code `<?php`

Comment: I know this myself, but this file is itself built automatically ,

Comment: Ah, you need to check the path of `txt` file

Comment: Where is this file?

Comment: It shows error `The requested URL /txt.txt was not found on this server.`

Comment: What URL do you use (see in browser address bar) when this happens? I need to know if this is served by your Apache from XAMPP or something else.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/

Comment: @i.man.ah Thanks for the URL. I've removed `phpstorm` tag as it has nothing to do with it (site is handled by Apache and not PhpStorm's built-in simple web server). I've also added `wordpress` tag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem.
I had an external reference in the themes functions.php. This contained a reference to a not existing website.

I don't know where the external reference came from, because it doesn't exist in my theme download.

Comment: oh my god , tnx , my problem is also solve ,and for my also  external refrence come from ,http://www.merna.cc/ ,whats this ?this code where is from ?

Comment: That's also my question left, how did it get in my code?

Comment: Based on the fact that quite a few of you had similar issue at the same time means that one of the plugins may contain some bad code (or some another form of "bad server side code injection"). Accordingly to WHOIS `merna.cc` domain was registered less than 2 weeks ago. Right now it's stopped working -- quite likely it's some malware/bad code somewhere (at very least that's how it looks from the side).

Comment: My assumption was correct. More info here -- https://www.rastating.com/malware-being-distributed-with-wordpress-plugins/